# Kingfisher cache image to disk

Tags: ios, uikit, kingfisher

```
for url in status.storedPicURLS! {
            group.enter()
            print("\(status.storedPicURLS)")
            KingfisherManager.shared.downloader.downloadImage(with: url, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (image, _, _, _) in
                print(" \(image)")
                group.leave()
            })
        }
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        finished(list, nil)
    }
```

I can get the image in the Console, but I can not find them in the Caches.

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7AF33AA9-220E-4B54-9830-  AA94226C16E8/data/Containers/Data/Application/451F885E-1DFF-4E57-A0D7-B3DEC880DF8F/Library/Caches/
```

[image: image description here]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The downloader (`ImageDownloader`) has nothing to do with cache. If you want to download and cache (as well as retrieve the cached images later), you should use the manager method: `KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage` instead of downloader standalone.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks for your reply and your library.

Answer (score 0):

See this extract from the documentation:

```
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, completionHandler: { 
    (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in
    // image: Image? `nil` means failed
    // error: NSError? non-`nil` means failed
    // cacheType: CacheType
    //                  .none - Just downloaded
    //                  .memory - Got from memory cache
    //                  .disk - Got from memory Disk
    // imageUrl: URL of the image
})
```

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet

Check what the result of cacheType is. It might not be stored in a disk cache.

Do this:

```
        KingfisherManager.shared.downloader.downloadImage(with: url, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: {  (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in
            print("\(imageUrl), from cache: \(cacheType)")
            group.leave()
        })
```

Paste output.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.

Comment: `for url in status.storedPicURLS! {
                group.enter()
                KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (_, _, _, _) in
                    group.leave()
                })
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            finished(list, nil)
        }
`

Comment: Use the function I modified in my answer, then print(cacheType)

Comment:  Optional(http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/c5ff030ejw1f8w502k1pej21bs0jw10y.jpg)
 Optional(http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/c5ff030ejw1f8w5039j6fj21a408saf5.jpg)
 Optional(http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/aa1f155cjw1f8vgtyyt9jj20bn00xt8k.jpg)
 Optional(http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/a841894bgw1f8vtfjc2dyj20zk0qo10s.jpg)
 Optional(http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/c5ff030ejw1f8v10krrs7j20x40lcadn.jpg)
 Optional(http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/6e1068adjw1f8v5xnxwmbj20l20cy759.jpg)
I got them in console, but still find nothing in Caches. How should I do with cacheType?

Comment: I updated my answer to print cacheType. Update that section of your code and paste the results.

Comment: Optional(731 bytes), from cache: Optional(http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/c5ff030ejw1f8w503qp2nj215g02cace.jpg)
Optional(714 bytes), from cache: Optional(http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/aa1f155cjw1f8vgtyyt9jj20bn00xt8k.jpg)
Optional(1195 bytes), from cache: Optional(http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/c5ff030ejw1f8w5039j6fj21a408saf5.jpg)

Comment: '/// Completion block of downloader.
public typealias ImageDownloaderCompletionHandler = ((Image?, NSError?, URL?, Data?) -> ())'     The third paramer in the block is URL?, no CacheType.

Comment: ``` for url in status.storedPicURLS! {
                group.enter()
                KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (_, _, _, _) in
                    group.leave()
                })
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            finished(list, nil)
        }
```